# How to reference the whole figure with subfig?

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

I'm using the `subfig` package in the following way:

```
Samples of our recordings are shown in the Figure XXXXX. 
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[`One']{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{One.eps} \label{fig:One}}\qquad
\subfloat[`Two']{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{Two.eps} \label{fig:Two}}\\
\subfloat[`Three']{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{Three.eps} \label{fig:Three}}\\
\parbox{15cm}{\vspace{0.4cm}
\caption{The caption goes here.}}
\end{figure}
```

I'd like to have the XXXXX replaced with something like `\ref{fig:TheWholeFigure}`, so that I can refer to the *whole figure*, e.g. "Figure 3" (and not each part e.g. "Figure 3b").

How could I achieve this?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `\parbox`?

Comment: I use it to customise the total width of the caption. Basically I want my caption width to be different from the main body (surrounding paragraphs etc.) width, so that it is nicer on the eye. 15cm goes well with A4 and the margin sizes that I use.

Comment: For that purpose it's better to use the `caption` package.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the suggestion. (So that we have something written here on this webpage) Could you summarise in a sentence or two why it is 'better'? I guess this is related to the anti-logic below.

Answer (score 4):

Just found a solution:

Stick the label for the whole figure inside the caption environment.

It doesn't seem to work anywhere else. E.g. it can't be after the caption, inside the parbox, or after the parbox, inside the figure environment. I'm not sure about the logic behind this.

Comment: Not inside the caption but *put a label for the figure environment* is the logic.

Comment: It is just that `\label` refers to the last command called before it that changed a counter (either a section, a figure, a table and so on...). In your example your labels referred to the subfloat commands and thus to the subfigures. By adding a `\label` after (or inside) the `\caption` for the whole figure it will allow you to get a link to this whole figure and not to all the subfigures.

Comment: @percusse Please see my edit.

Comment: It works inside the `\parbox` after the `\caption` command.  But you should not be using a `\parbox` anyway.  Just write `\caption{...}\label{...}`.  If you need to adjust vertical spacing   you can write the previous double backslash as `\\[0.4cm]`.